# Select does not return values Postgres-11.4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I am using pgAdmin-4 and created a database with a single table, but select returns an error message: 'table oid'

I'm using a normal select query.

```
SELECT * FROM escola
```

This happens with PostgreSQL 11.4.

Comment: What was the command you typed and what are the details of the error message? Akso what is the version number of Postgres?

Comment: Hello, im using a normal select ( select * from escola) and im using PostgreSQL 11.4

Comment: This is not an issue with pgAdmin4 but with the Debian/Ubuntu packaging, Debian/Ubuntu repo has older version of psycopg2 library.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem is due to python3-psycopg2. The latest pgadmin4 version requires psycopg2-2.8. But if you're on Debian/Ubuntu stable, apt installed v2.7.
So you need to update it with pip :

```sh
sudo pip3 install -U psycopg2
```

Then update the pgadmin4 config to add the local python path:

```sh
nano ~/.config/pgadmin/pgadmin4.conf 
# or with a right click on the system tray icon
# add /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages to the PythonPath.
```

Same thing with python3.7 (just change the lib path)

Hope this helps.

Comment: This answer gave me a very good direction. Installing or updating `psycopg2` didn't work for me since it required `pg_config` which I couldn't find. Instead I did: `pip3 install psycopg2-binary` which succeeded without asking any config. Then, I modified proposed above `pgadmin4.conf` file by setting `PythonPath` in the following way: `PythonPath="/home/rustam/.local/lib/python3.6;/home/rustam/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages"` . After that my `SELECT` queries stopped returning `table_oid` and I can see results fine.

Comment: Thank you very much, the instructions worked. I only had to install setuptools "sudo pip3 install -U setuptools" before installing psycopg2.

Comment: @Rustam Aliyev In our case, when setting the PythonPath the devider had to be a `:` instead of `;`  `PythonPath="/home/rustam/.local/lib/python3.6:/home/rustam/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages"`

Comment: I want to add something for this. if `sudo pip3 install -U psycopg2` didn't work install pip3 by `sudo apt install python-pip` and then run `sudo pip3 install -U psycopg2` again. running `pip3 install -U psycopg2` to me didn't solve the problem, I have to install pip3 in sudo and run `sudo pip3 install -U psycopg2` and then don't forget to update the pgadmin4 conf

Comment: Followed Rustam's approach, but used `PythonPath=/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages` in the pgadmin4.conf, and restarted the pgadmin server process.

Comment: I can't find pgadmin4.conf. My initial version of postgresql was 9.4. Indeed, psql -V returns version 9.4.23. However, the command pg_config --version returns 11.4. I have the same issue as the question and I don't know what to do...

Comment: ok, after suffering with this issue and trying to fix python libs, I just installed DBeaver and everything looks good now !

Answer (score -3):

after I updated my pgAdmin 4 today I'm getting the same message 'table_oid' from select queries I execute in pgAdmin 4.

The odd thing is when I execute the view data command from GUI it works perfectly.

When I execute a select search from query tool I got the 'table_oid' message, as same as Maykon Morais.

I tried to add a comment on Maykon Morais' question (telling I got the same problem) but i don't have enough reputation yet :-\

The table_oid message appear, in my case, when running a simple select from the query tool window of pgadmin4.

Postgres version:
psql (PostgreSQL) 11.4 (Ubuntu 11.4-1.pgdg18.04+1)

pgAdmin4 version:
Versión
4.11
Derechos de Autor
Copyright (C) 2013 - 2019, The pgAdmin Development Team
Versión de Python
3.6.8 (default, Jan 14 2019, 11:02:34) [GCC 8.0.1 20180414 (experimental) [trunk revision 259383]]
Versión de Flask
0.12.2
Modo de Aplicación
Escritorio
Usuario Actual
pgadmin4@pgadmin.org

---

### Trying to give a properly answer

Well the workaround that I see (and I'm using myself right now) meanwhile this situation is fixed, securely soon, is to execute select queries via console:

1. login as postgres user: sudo su postgres
2. psql -h dbhostname -U dbusername -d dbname
3. SELECT * FROM dbtable;

=)