# pgAdmin4 Query Error "not enough values to unpack (expected 5, got 4)"

Tags: python, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I can't run queries on pgAdmin4 on Ubuntu 19.04. I can view data through pgAdmin and execute queries through my terminal. However, whenever I try to use the query tool I get the error `not enough values to unpack (expected 5, got 4)`.

I've tried reinstalling pgAdmin and psycopg2. Following this guide https://www.osradar.com/how-to-install-pgadmin-on-ubuntu-19-04/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had the same problem on Debian Buster. I had psycopg2 installed through pip3 to solve the [older problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57226520/select-does-not-return-values-postgres-11-4) with no returns in pgadmin on Debian.

So now i went to pgadmin config (right mouse button to pgadmin icon in tray) and **deleted** the custom path to python libraries. After that it works great.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried this but sadly it didn't work. I ended up just using a pgAdmin4 docker container.

Comment: Thank you so much. PGAdmin's query tool breaks every other day ;)

Comment: Thanks for the fix. pgAdmin4 has had 2 major defects in the past weeks. It's ridiculous.

Answer (score 3):

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04, running pgAdmin4 4.11 in Desktop mode.  As user1936789 suggested, clearing the Python Path on the Python tab of the PgAdmin 4 Configuration screen cleared up the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Ubuntu 19.04 with pgAdmin 4 - 4.11.
The problem is in python unpack of params. There is a known issue in pgAdmin site.

I changed the python file as suggested and it worked like a charm!

see issue: [pgAdmin 4 issue](https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/4640#change-17969)